# JavaScript, Parse.com count queries return nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, restangular

I'm working on my personal website with Restangular and Parse.com for communication between server and client.

However when I tried to get the total count of entries in a class from Parse, nothing seemed to be returned and console.log showed nothing as well.

These are parts of the code from the server:

```
exports.getCount = function (req, res) {
    var Article = Parse.Object.extend('Articles');
    var artQuery = new Parse.Query(Article);
    artQuery.count({
        success: function(num) {
            console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + num);
            res.json(num);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            res.status(500).end();
        }
    });
};
```

This is how I request the data from the client side:

```
$scope.count = function(){
    Restangular.all('api/things/count').getList().then(function (data) {
        alert(data); // This gives Undefined
        $scope.max = data[0];
    });
}
```

And finally this is the route:

```
router.get('/count', controller.getCount);
```

Comment: try to put a console message in `error` function as well and let us know if any error happens

Comment: I put a console message under `error` function but nothing happened

Comment: Are you sure your getCount function is being called?

Comment: @Seeya Yes, I am pretty sure.

Comment: Maybe you can use chrome's network inspector to view what's the response after invoking getCount function.